# Вывод пересечения списков по убыванию

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как мне вывести результат пересечения по убыванию совпавших чисел ?

```
a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,40,33,48]
b = [[1, 24, 13, 33, 29, 1, 10], [29, 34, 1, 26, 27, 8, 10], [3, 15,35, 24, 48, 1, 6],[6, 12, 23, 26, 18, 3, 9], [28, 40, 13, 29, 48, 9, 4], [14, 13, 5, 36, 44, 8, 1],[48, 9, 33, 26, 40, 4, 7], [21, 28, 14, 12, 7, 9, 1], [37, 39, 8, 47, 45, 4, 2],[34, 20, 37, 33, 40, 1, 2]]

for r, i in sorted(([list(set(a) & set(i)), i] for i in b), key=lambda l: l[0], reverse=True):
print(i , '----' ,r)
```

Вывод сейчас:

```
[3, 15, 35, 24, 48, 1, 6] ---- [48, 1, 3, 6]
[28, 40, 13, 29, 48, 9, 4] ---- [40, 48, 4]
[34, 20, 37, 33, 40, 1, 2] ---- [40, 33, 2, 1]
[48, 9, 33, 26, 40, 4, 7] ---- [33, 4, 7, 40, 48]
[6, 12, 23, 26, 18, 3, 9] ---- [3, 6]
[37, 39, 8, 47, 45, 4, 2] ---- [2, 4]
[1, 24, 13, 33, 29, 1, 10] ---- [1, 33]
[21, 28, 14, 12, 7, 9, 1] ---- [1, 7]
[14, 13, 5, 36, 44, 8, 1] ---- [1, 5]
[29, 34, 1, 26, 27, 8, 10] ---- [1]
```

а я хочу получить такой вывод:

```
[48, 9, 33, 26, 40, 4, 7] ---- [33, 4, 7, 40, 48]
[34, 20, 37, 33, 40, 1, 2] ---- [40, 33, 2, 1]
[3, 15, 35, 24, 48, 1, 6] ---- [48, 1, 3, 6]
[28, 40, 13, 29, 48, 9, 4] ---- [40, 48, 4]
[1, 24, 13, 33, 29, 1, 10] ---- [1, 33]
[6, 12, 23, 26, 18, 3, 9] ---- [3, 6]
[37, 39, 8, 47, 45, 4, 2] ---- [2, 4]
[14, 13, 5, 36, 44, 8, 1] ---- [1, 5]
[21, 28, 14, 12, 7, 9, 1] ---- [1, 7]
[29, 34, 1, 26, 27, 8, 10] ---- [1]
```

например нашел в десятом списке 5 чисел вывел их первыми , в пятом списке нашел 3 числа вывел их вторыми , в третьем списке нашел 1 число вывел его третьим .....

Answer (score 1):

```
for r, i in sorted(([list(set(a) & set(i)), i] for i in b), key=lambda l: l[0], reverse=True):
    print(i , '----' ,r)
```

Comment: Спасибо с тем списком все сработало , я немного поменял вопрос , как мне так решить эту задачу)

Answer (score 0):

```py
a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
b = [[9,9,9],[23,23,23],[0,8,9,10], [0,1,13,15],[0,1,2,3],[0,1,2,3,4,5],[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]]

for i in reversed(b):
    result=list(set(a) & set(i))
    print(i , '----' ,result)
```

Comment: не сработает, т.к. после [0,8,9,10] выведет [23,23,23]

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно просто отсортировать список `b`

```
a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
b = [[9,9,9],[23,23,23],[0,8,9,10], [0,1,13,15],[0,1,2,3],[0,1,2,3,4,5],[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]]

for i in sorted(b):
    result=list(set(a) & set(i))
    print(i , '----' ,result)
```

Comment: Здравствуйте , я немного поменял вопрос , как мне так решить эту задачу)